# Confusion in Windows 8 navigation

Tags: c#, windows-8, navigation, microsoft-metro

I  am confused about two way of navigating from one page to another in Windows 8.

**First one** :-

using a frame that is defined initially in App.Xaml.cs class like this.

```
 public static Frame RootFrame;

 protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
 {
      RootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
 }
```

navigating through it like..

```
App.RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
```

**Second one** :- 
It is simple way of navigation like..

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(page1));
```

question :- Is there any difference in these two types , if yes please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the same method, in fact operating on the same object.  Your application object creates a `Frame` object that hosts pages (in the basic app template, when the application is first launched, note that if `rootFrame` is null, it news up a `Frame` and sets it to `Window.Current.Context`).

From that point forward, you are using navigation functions of that same `Frame` object.  When you navigate to `Page1`, the `Frame` sets the `Page1.Frame` property to itself, so in `Page1`, `this.Frame` points at the same object as `App.RootFrame` (essentially a "parent" link).

So, `Window.Current.Content` hosts a `Frame` object, and that object hosts `Page`s. Each `Page` has a pointer back to that `Frame` which they can use to command that `Frame` to Navigate to other `Page`s.

Note that `Window.Current.Content` itself is a SETTABLE `UiElement`. That means it could technically host UI other than a `Frame`.  This could be used to (for example) make some chrome that itself hosted a `Frame` which was the actual content of your app (like the HTML iFrames of old).  I did this in one case in order to create a developer console that was easily invokable/usable from every page of my application (because it existed ABOVE the level of the frame hosting the individual pages).